# Filename pattern validation in adf v2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I would like to validate my input filename whether it's in specified name.
Like my filename should be <>*<>*<>_<>.csv

Yes i am using event based i will get filename from trigger.

expected format: company_contry_yearmonth_timestamp.CSV

Comment: Can you share the file source and a sample pattern

Comment: Are you using trigger ? how is your file input setup ?

Comment: i have updated my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit regex way of validating if the incoming file name matches a pattern. But if you are using activity like lookup or copy  activity. You can specify in the source dataset settings a wildcard file name or file path to **fetch** a file matching the pattern.

[- wildcardFileName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#:%7E:text=characters%20under%20the%20given-,container,-and%20folder%20path%20(or))

> The file name with wildcard characters under the given container and
> folder path (or wildcard folder path) to filter source files. Allowed
> wildcards are: * (matches zero or more characters) and ? (matches zero
> or single character). Use ^ to escape if your file name has a wildcard
> or this escape character inside. See more examples in Folder and file
> filter examples.

**example:**

You can use a if condition, with an expression as below using **contains()**

Here a storage event trigger, gets the trigged file name into a parameter. We then use contains() function to see if the file name contains a specified string

```
@contains(pipeline().parameters.filenameTriggered,'pattern')
```

[image]

[image]

If true a wait activity is executed.

[image]

Comment: How can I give my expected format in contains

Comment: in place of 'pattern' in my snip example, you can hard code or use variable to dynamically store or use date functions to set the year month or timestamp

Comment: I had a file `thispattern.csv` that triggered pipeline and as you can seen in the expression 'pattern' is a substring in the file name